# Keycloak service is not initialized in AppComponent and I need it to read language from token for translation

Tags: angular

I'm using Keycloak service to return a token with the language setting in it and I store that in localStorage.

My issue currently is, I cannot read from Keycloak service in AppComponent because the token is not yet initialized there, and so I have that in an internal module.

So, in the internal component call it `user-settings.component.ts`, I check localStorage lang against Keycloak lang from token like this:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("lang") != tokenParsed.language)
{
    if (tokenParsed.language == "ar") { 
      this.localStorageUtilsService.setItem("lang", "ar"); 
    }
    else if (tokenParsed.language == "en") { 
      this.localStorageUtilsService.setItem("lang", "en"); 
    }
}
```

That code handles changing the language, but the problem is, the first reload after changing the language, half the system would be in Arabic and half of it in English, and that's because when I set the language here, "half" the application would've been already loaded, and that's why I need to set localStorage before this point, in AppComponent.

The workaround I did was to add this `window.location.reload();` after those if statements, that way I reload the page midway through (but it's a nightmare).

Comment: Which solution are you using to translate the app? is it ngx-translate? What do you think about [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER)? Could that be of help?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I am using ngx-translate yes. I'm currently looking into how to implement what you suggested, hope it works! Also thanks a lot for it!